# How to mock a React Component with complicated logic

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, mocking, jestjs

I am using a third-party React component which is proving really hard to test. Here is an example of what my component looks like.

```
import { ThirdPartySelect } from 'thirdPartyComponents'
function Select() {
  /* Lots of complicated logic */
  ...
  const [name, changeName] = useState('First Name')
  const options = [
    'First Name',
    'Second Name',
    'First Name',
  ]

  function handleChange(event) {
    changeName(event)
  }

  return (
   <ThirdPartySelect onChange={handleChange()} options={options} value={name}/>
  )
}
```

It turns out that this is really hard to test because the Select component is actually like 4 HTML elements, and it's tough to figure out which one to trigger.
Looking around, it seems like [this guy](https://www.polvara.me/posts/testing-a-custom-select-with-react-testing-library/) had a pretty good solution for how to solve the problem. He mocked the component and made it so there was only like on HTML component, which made it much easier to change.

The problem I'm running into now is that the code shown can be pretty easily mocked, but when it says

```
/* Lots of complicated logic */
```

there are about 100 lines of code because the component is using React-Redux, and it made things really messy.

In theory, I could add all of the Redux logic to the mock, but I figure that it might get changed at some point in the component itself, which would require me to change that in the mocked component as well, and that could get very messy.

**So here's my question**: is there a way to mock just the simple React components that I showed in the example, while not having to add the redux logic, but still being able to include the redux logic in the mocked component? Or do I have to physically code out anything that I want to add to the mocked component?

The reason I want to include the Redux logic is because that's what I actually want to test.

Sorry if this question sounds kind of naive, I'm new to Jest and am having a tough time understanding how everything works.

Comment: What is the "lots of complicated logic"? That is a flag to me that it should be factored out as a utility function that (a) is easily testable in isolation, and (b) easily mockable later. Also, hopefully you didn't mean that you are actually unit testing third party code, but rather it is just making your component hard to test.

Comment: I'm no testing the third-party code, it's just making my methods harder to test. That being said, you think I should put all of the Redux code in a utility function? I'll look into that. It seems like it might be kind of complicated, but maybe it's the better way to structure my components

Comment: What kind of redux code do you have *in* your component code? Redux hooks I assume? Do you mind sharing your component code here? May be able to point out easily extractable functionality.

Comment: So I have redux hooks, but I also have some useEffect functions in place because my component gets information from a server, and sometimes it needs to be parsed. So with the parsing, and listener hooks from Redux hooks, it becomes a lot

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like this got much traction. I realized that even though I had a lot of logic in the component, most of it what stuff that happens when an action occurs and affects this component, as opposed to when this component changed.

For that reason, I decided to just mock the component with the small amount of logic that triggers when the component changes. This wasn't the 100 lines of logic I was worried about.

Other than that, I used the regular component when it is on the receiving end of an action. The reason for this is because it's much easier to determine if something happened to the component than it is to trigger the action.